# Zend_Validate: Db_NoRecordExists with Doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

Hey there, I'm trying to validate a form with Zend_Validate and Zend_Form.

My element:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'validator' => 'Db_NoRecordExists',
            'options' => array('user','username')
            )
    )
));
```

For I use Doctrine to handle my database, Zend_Validate misses a DbAdapter. I could pass an adapter in the options, but how do I combine Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract and Doctrine?

Is there maybe an easyer way to get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it with an own Validator:

```
<?php

class Validator_NoRecordExists extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    private $_table;
    private $_field;

    const OK = '';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::OK => "'%value%' ist bereits in der Datenbank"
    );

    public function __construct($table, $field) {
        if(is_null(Doctrine::getTable($table)))
            return null;

        if(!Doctrine::getTable($table)->hasColumn($field))
            return null;

        $this->_table = Doctrine::getTable($table);
        $this->_field = $field;
    }

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->_setValue($value);

        $funcName = 'findBy' . $this->_field;

        if(count($this->_table->$funcName($value))>0) {
            $this->_error();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Used like that:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'validator' => new Validator_NoRecordExists('User','username')
            )
    )
));
```